# MVVM for Winforms architecture

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, mvvm, architecture

I have a Windows Forms application which is implemented using the MVVM architecture with a custom MVP framework developed by me.

My presenters have the following signature (for example) :

```
public abstract class Presenter<TView, TModel> : Presenter<TView>, IPresenter<TView, TModel>, IPresenter<TView>, IPresenter, IDisposable
    where TView : class, IView<TModel>
    where TModel : ViewModelBase//, new()
{
```

and a concrete implementation:

```
internal class EditCustomerPresenter : Presenter<IEditCustomerView, EditCustomerViewModel>, IEditCustomerPresenter
{
    public EditCustomerPresenter(IEditCustomerView view, EditCustomerViewModel model)
        : base(view, model)
    {
        view.Title = "Editar cliente";
    }
}
```

I have a presenter factory with the following methods :

```
    public static DialogResult ShowView<TIView, TIModel>()
        where TIView : class, IView<TIModel>
        where TIModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    }
```

and :

```
    public static DialogResult ShowView<TIView, TIModel>(TIModel model)
        where TIView : class, IView<TIModel>
        where TIModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    }
```

So If I want to create a new Customer I can create an instance of the view like this:

```
PresenterFactory.ShowView<IEditCustomerView, EditCustomerViewModel>(new EditCustomerViewModel()
{
    Entity = new CustomerEntity()
}
```

My problem is with the architecture of this, if I want to get the entity from the database where should this code be placed? Should the presenter be responsable of loading the entity from the database? something like :

```
PresenterFactory.ShowView<IEditCustomerView, EditCustomerViewModel>(new EditCustomerViewModel() , p => p.LoadCustomer(customerId));
```